# How to customize Textbox in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to create or customize the textbox in CRM 2011.If i enter the text in that text box it will show the link,which means to create the text box with link.like this,

How to do this?Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CRM 2011 you need to change the format for the type `Single Line of Text` when you customize the field.

[image]

You can choose `E-mail` (it will open the e-mail client) or `URL` (it will open the browser)